# Youtube Iframe load only when thumbnail image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Youtube Iframe load on thumb click</title>

    <style>
        .youtube {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .youtube iframe, .youtube object, .youtube embed {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .youtube__img {
            bottom: 0;
            display: block;
            left: 0;
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: auto;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .youtube__play {
            height: 72px;
            width: 72px;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -36px;
            margin-top: -36px;
            position: absolute;
            background: url("http://i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png") no-repeat;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto">


<div class="youtube" data-id="JLf9q36UsBk"></div>


<p>Credits to <a href="http://embedresponsively.com/">embedresponsively.com for Responsive embed</a>, <a href="http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/">labnol.org For the javascript functionality</a></p>

<script>
    (function () {
        var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube");
        for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
            var p = document.createElement("div");
            p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
            p.onclick = labnolIframe;
            v[n].appendChild(p);
        }
    })();

    function labnolThumb(id) {
        return '<img class="youtube__img" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="youtube__play"></div>';
    }

    function labnolIframe() {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1");
        iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**What it is supposed to do?**
This is going to make page faster to load if you have youtube iframe in your page. This code will replace all divs like

```
<div class="youtube" data-id="JLf9q36UsBk"></div>
```

With youtube thumbnail image. And only when user clicks on it it will load the iframe.

This is a mix I've made based on labnol script and embed resposively. (basically I just renamed and removed some classes)
demo on codepen http://codepen.io/AucT/pen/PzvyXq

Help improve code. I want it to be as efficient as possible.
p.s. you can use jQuery

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. We know how expectant you are about reviewing your code but we can't take any actions  till you have added a context to your code to explain what your code does?  your statement "I'm not that in javascript. p.s. you can use jQuery" is very confusing

Comment: added description

Comment: `I want it to be as efficient as possible` - what is your definition of `efficient`? Do you see low performance confirmed by js profiler or timeline snapshot? The code is simple and straightforward, the only possible change can be style and other insignificant modifications, if you don't want to go full HTML5 and use custom elements thus losing support of old browsers without a polyfill but that won't be `efficient`.